# java.lang.IllegalStateException при выборе файлов из памяти устройства

Tags: java, android, файлы

Доброе время суток! Столкнулся со следующей проблемой:
Попадаю в окно выбора файла или фотографии с помощью такого интента:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_FOR_AVATAR_UPLOAD);
```

Получаю в методе OnActivityResult путь к файлу:

```
 String path = getRealPathFromURI(selectedImageUri);
    java.io.File file = new java.io.File(path);
    uploadAvatar(file);
```

Метод getRealPathFromURI(selectedImageUri) выглядит следующим образом:

```
private String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentURI) {
        String result;
        Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver()
                .query(contentURI, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor == null) {
            result = contentURI.getPath();
        } else {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
            result = cursor.getString(idx);
            cursor.close();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

В итоге на версии API 24 получаю следующую ошибку при выборе файла/фотографии:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                Process: com.example.uncolor.zachetka, PID: 1943
                                                                                java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=131072, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image:27 flg=0x1 }} to activity {com.example.uncolor.zachetka/com.example.uncolor.zachetka.MainActivity_}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4053)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4096)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1516)
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
                                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
                                                                                    at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetString(Native Method)
                                                                                    at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:438)
                                                                                    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:51)
                                                                                    at android.database.CursorWrapper.getString(CursorWrapper.java:137)
                                                                                    at com.example.uncolor.zachetka.fragments.ProfileFragment.getRealPathFromURI(ProfileFragment.java:320)
                                                                                    at com.example.uncolor.zachetka.fragments.ProfileFragment.onActivityResult(ProfileFragment.java:156)
                                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onActivityResult(FragmentActivity.java:156)
                                                                                    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6917)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4049)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4096) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1516) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755) 
    06-26 05:58:16.673 504-517/system_process E/NetworkManagement: Error closing sockets after enabling chain standby: android.os.ServiceSpecificException: destroySockets: No such file or directory
```

На версии 5.1 данная ошибка отсутствует. На версии API 24 в данном окне при выборе фото приложение вылетает. Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Заранее благодарю за помощь!

Comment: Начиная с API 24 запрещено в `Intent` передавать `Uri` типа `file://` - думаю связано с этим. Почитайте [например здесь](https://medium.com/@sauge16/targetting-sdkversion-24-android-nougat-and-above-and-sharing-file-through-intent-3f0f0128fa7e)

Comment: Но у меня везде тип content://

Answer (score 0):

Кажется разобрался/вспомнил как это делалось. Сто лет назад для своего прожекта делал форк одного довольно известной либы. Уже и не помню, что я там менял, но в проекте у меня все работает.

Посмотрите [на этот код](https://github.com/ivanovpv/aFileChooser/blob/master/aFileChooser/src/com/ipaulpro/afilechooser/utils/FileUtils.java)

Там смысл в том, что надо делать ветвление на API уровням. Основной метод, который далее вызывает еще тучу мелких утилит такой:

```
/**
     * Get a file path from a Uri. This will get the the path for Storage Access
     * Framework Documents, as well as the _data field for the MediaStore and
     * other file-based ContentProviders.<br>
     * <br>
     * Callers should check whether the path is local before assuming it
     * represents a local file.
     * 
     * @param context The context.
     * @param uri The Uri to query.
     * @see #isLocal(String)
     * @see #getFile(Context, Uri)
     * @author paulburke
     */
    public static String getPath(final Context context, final Uri uri) {

        if (DEBUG)
            Log.d(TAG + " File -",
                    "Authority: " + uri.getAuthority() +
                            ", Fragment: " + uri.getFragment() +
                            ", Port: " + uri.getPort() +
                            ", Query: " + uri.getQuery() +
                            ", Scheme: " + uri.getScheme() +
                            ", Host: " + uri.getHost() +
                            ", Segments: " + uri.getPathSegments().toString()
                    );

        final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;

        // DocumentProvider
        if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
            // LocalStorageProvider
            if (isLocalStorageDocument(uri)) {
                // The path is the id
                return DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            }
            // ExternalStorageProvider
            else if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];

                if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                    return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
                }

                // TODO handle non-primary volumes
            }
            // DownloadsProvider
            else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {

                final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                        Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));

                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
            }
            // MediaProvider
            else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];

                Uri contentUri = null;
                if ("image".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                }

                final String selection = "_id=?";
                final String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {
                        split[1]
                };

                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
            }
        }
        // MediaStore (and general)
        else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {

            // Return the remote address
            if (isGooglePhotosUri(uri))
                return uri.getLastPathSegment();

            return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
        }
        // File
        else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            return uri.getPath();
        }

        return null;
    }
```